# replace '&' character with reg exp in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, special-characters

I'd like to replace the "&" character, along with characters that may interfere with urls syntax.

so far i tried:

```
myText = myText.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-. ]/g,'');
```

that probably works for other characters (didn't test it) but didn't comprehend the "&" which is what i care most about, so i added in combo the following line but also didn't get rid of the &:

```
myText = myText.replace(/&/g,'');
```

but neither work, how can i replace this special character?

**SOLUTION:**

Code was reading `&amp;` at delivery and not `&`, so i had to do:

```
myText = myText.replace(/&amp;/g,'');
```

and it works.

**SNIPPET:**

```js
var text = "god & damn it";
console.log(text.replace(/&amp;|&/g,''));
```

Comment: `"a&a".replace(/&/g,'');` is `"aa"` - if your not seeing that then something else is wrong ...  If this is something to do with html/url encoding then you should add more details.

Comment: I just tested .replace(/&/g, ' ') and it worked for me. Can you show more of your code? It might be assigning it again.

Comment: Maybe the `&` you are seeing are encoded when reaching your code, for intance when you see that character in some page, in the code it can be `&amp;` or in an url it can be `%26`. They all end up looking like an  `&` but they are encoded.

Comment: I think i got it, i think it's because it's reading the code &amp; instead, console logs me ampn then amp instead of &

Comment: @notsure In that case please either update your question so that it contains a [mcve] and optionally add your own answer so that the rest of the world can benefit from it, or delete your question. The way it is written now, it's off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can't delete it says other people have answered. Anyway was partially the &amp; thing, and also the fact i called that text again below with a different var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments, what you are trying to replace is this `&amp;`, the html encoding of the `&` character.

**With lodash** you can [`_.unescape`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#unescape) the string before replacing:

```
myText = _.unescape(myText).replace(/&/g, '');
```

This way you handle both `&` and `&amp;` cases. Then if you have to append that text in the html you should [`_.escape`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#escape) it back to prevent weird side effects: `_.escape(myText);`.

**Without lodash** you can just search both in your regex:

```
myText = myText.replace(/&amp;|&/g, '');
```

**But** this method can have it's side effects when other special characters are present because it removes the `&` character too, for example this string `"Three is &gt; than two &amp; one"` would end up looking like this `"Three is gt; than two  one"` (notice the ugly **gt;** in the middle)

Comment: I like your second solution with "or": myText = myText.replace(/&amp;|&/g, ''); giving an upvote for the improvement

Comment: Can you check this answer as _correct_ if this is working for you? Thanks!

Comment: Well I found about the &amp; by myself so little changes with adding |&, but here you go.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log("m&yText".replace(/\&/g,''))`

I can suggest adding the backslash character before the & as to 'escape' using the & as the regex character. You want the regex to find and replace any literal & character.